# Symfony2/Doctrine2 searchable behavior?

Tags: symfony, full-text-search, doctrine-orm, searchable

Why the searchable behavior has been removed from doctrine2? I have not found any trace of that in Doctrine Extensions (https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle), nor I have found any resources about the topic. Anyone can help me?

Comment: just an advice: take a look at sphinx search

Comment: I don't remember having ever seen a searchable behavior in gedmo's extensions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you search a really simple searchable system, you can look at https://github.com/knplabs/DoctrineBehaviors#filterable and https://github.com/KnpLabs/ControllerBehaviors/blob/master/src/Knp/ControllerBehaviors/FilterableBehavior.php

It's a set of traits (php5.4) that helps you to create simple filter forms.

Comment: Thanks Florian, but I need a behavior which is able to (like the old searchable) index the specified fields of the entity, in order to perform a full text search over the repository.